# Regarding Class in CSS

Tags: css

In one of the sample templates the CSS file had this:

```
div.wrapper{display:block; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:left;}
```

In the HTML source code:

```
<div class="wrapper row2">
```

Why, as is in this case class is not used this way `.wrapper` and then describe its properties ? Could you please describe the purpose of `div.wrapper`

Comment: why do you say not `.wrapper` is not used?

Comment: take a look at css specificity . that might answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class might be there for good purposes, since its a template with alot of styles. some overrides others,

it also could be there by mistake since div is already a `block element` and it will spin 100% of width by default, the only useful codes there are for `padding` and `margin` offseting.

but again check the whole css styles as you might find there is some styles he's trying to override for some purposes